# Why is it not possible to call functions directly from an object without function expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function Car(make, model) {
    this.make = make
    this.model = model

    console.log(" Iam inside the object" )
    this.whatsmymodel = function () {
        console.log(" Iam " , this.model)
    }

    function whatsmymake() {
        console.log(" Iam " , this.make)
    }
}

function whatsthis() {
    console.log (" This is a function")
}

Car.prototype.whoami = function () {
        console.log(" Iam " , this.make + " " + this.model)
}

var tesla = new Car("Tesla", "ModelS")
tesla.whoami()
tesla.whatsmymodel()
tesla.whatsmymake() // Error!!

whatsthis()
```

How come I get error for tesla.whatsmymake()

```
TypeError: tesla.whatsmymake is not a function
```

I understand it is possible in the new ES6 class but wouldnt it be easier to define a function within a function constructor ? 
It is letting me define but doesnt allow me to call - why is that ?

Comment: You didn't set `this.whatsmymake`. Simply defining a local function in a constructor does not make it a property of the constructed object. You have to make an explicit assignment.

Comment: function this.whatsmymake() {
             ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

Comment: Four lines above that you did it the right way!!!

Comment: it allows function expression but not function statement, seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: You can declare the function with a function declaration, and then assign it to an object property: `this.whatsmymake = whatsmymake;`

Comment: Agree but it sounds odd why function statements are not allowed.

Comment: The namespace of properties on an object is completely distinct from the namespace of local variables. The language simply was not designed to make that possible; in fact that would be a significant anti-feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141802/discussion-between-victor-and-pointy).

Comment: Do not confuse bindings and scope. They are two different things. Bindings, that is, defining what "methods" an object has is completely unrelated to scope.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a function called `whatsmymake` inside the lexical scope of the `Car` constructor, but you have not done anything to create a property  call `whatsmymake` on the `this` returned by the `Car` constructor. If every function defined inside the lexical scope of a constructor were attached to the constructed object, this would be very inconvenient, and would disallow the creation of helper methods inside the constructor without also attaching those helper methods to the constructed object. For example:

```
function Car() {
    this.rightWheelAngle = 0;
    this.leftWheelAngle = 0;

    this.turnLeft = function() { turnBothWheels(1); }
    this.turnRight = function() { turnBothWheels(-1); }

    function turnBothWheels(inc) {
        this.rightWheelAngle += inc;
        this.leftWheelAngle += inc;
    }
}
```

Suppose we do *not* want to expose `turnBothWheels` as a method on the returned object. JavaScript does not require you to do so, but you can still use the `turnBothWheels` function within functions that have lexical-scope visibility of that function (such as the `turnRight` and `turnLeft` methods, above).

As for why function declarations don't allow a property-access name-path like `function foo.bar.baz() { ... }`, they just don't -- function names must be plain identifiers. That's how the grammar is defined. If you want to have a function in a property named `baz` on the object stored in the property `bar` on the object `foo`, then simply do an assignment to store it there: `foo.bar.baz = function() { ... }`